# Word for a male aged 20 through 25

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, writing, names

I'm trying to come up with a word that describes a male aged from 20 through 25. Man feels too adult like and Young Adult feels like a teenager. The type of word I'm looking for is someone not yet middle aged, but is on his way there, but still retains some youthfulness.

Thank you for your response.

*Just to add on, any word using modern terms probably won't work, as it is being used in something set in a medieval / fantasy realm.*

> An edit to explain how. I am asking for a word that is referring to a male who is older than a young adult who still has a sense of youthfulness. An example would be someone about to graduate college, someone who feels too old to be called young (adult) but does not have the experiences or age yet to be considered middle aged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the context, perhaps *fellow*: "He was an amiable fellow". Using *fellow* intentionally avoids using 'boy', implying that the person isn't a boy or necessarily young. Likewise, I would think 'fellow' is too informal to describe an older person.

*Chap* or *gent* could also work, as a child certainly isn't a "gent".

Comment: OTOH, gent would probably be too formal to describe a young person ;)

Comment: I don't consider 'fellow' necessarily to relate to a *young* man (at least not in BrE) - it can be used to refer to any male.  You could refer to *young fellow*, but that really avoids the question.

Comment: @TimMalone Nowadays it would be, but one hundred years ago I shouldn't think so. Think of a 23 year old student at Oxford. Surely this would be a 'gent'.